# In Python, are the spaces important to code variable = 4 + 5 Or is it fine to code it as variable=4+5?

Tags: python

I started learning Python and I noticed that the website teaching me will usually write like this:
variable = 4 + 5

however even if I write:
variable=4+5

I still get no errors and it runs properly.

So are those spaces are important or not?

Comment: see the language reference https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/lexical_analysis.html#whitespace-between-tokens

Answer (score 0):

It is not important, but putting in spaces can be good form.

More in this book: https://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex4.html

Answer (score 0):

You don't write a program for a computer, you write it so it can be read by another human (or yourself in a few months).

`variable = 4 + 5` is easier to read than `variable=4+5`

If you want examples what not to write, you can take a look a [submissions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/172912/65905) for [code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score -1):

In Python, you use white spaces, where other languages uses brackets (), and Python uses enter instead of curly brackets {} and semicolons ;
Python ignores other enters and white spaces.